# Ansible local_action on host without local ssh daemon

Tags: ansible

How can I run a local command on a Ansible control server, if that control server does not have a SSH daemon running?

If I run the following playbook:

```
- name: Test commands
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Test local action
      local_action: command echo "hello world"
```

I get the following error:

`fatal: [localhost]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused", "unreachable": true}`

It seems that `local_action` is the same as `delegate_to: 127.0.0.1`, so Ansible tries to ssh to the localhost. However, there is no SSH daemon running on the local controller host (only on the remote machines).

So my immediate question is how to run a specific command from Ansible, without Ansible first trying to SSH to localhost.

---

Crucial addition, not in the original question:

My host_vars contained the following line:

```
ansible_connection: ssh
```

Comment: Try using `delegate_to: localhost` instead of `local_action`. It may be that `delegate_to: 127.0.0.1` will try to ssh to the local machine, but `delegate_to: localhost` does not use ssh.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> how to run a specific command from Ansible, without Ansible first trying to SSH to localhost.

`connection: local` is sufficient to make the tasks run in the controller without using SSH.

Try,

```
- name: Test commands
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Test local action
      command: echo "hello world"
```

Comment: Specifying a connection only seems possible in the playbook, not individually per task. So that's a limitation. but otherwise, I can largely work around it. E.g. by moving al local "preparation" tasks (such as rsync or testing if a connection works) to a separate playbook.

Comment: Alternatively you can define the `ansible_connection` as local for that host in the inventory and whenever a task has to be on the controller it will default to local connection. For other hosts it will go with SSH.

Comment: Thanks @franklinsijo: it seems that setting`ansible_connection: local` in the `vars` section of a Task did allow me to set per-task connection types. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'll answer the details myself, perhaps it is useful to someone:

In my case:

1. `ansible_connection` was set to `ssh` in the `host_vars`.
2. `ansible_host` was set to `localhost` by `local_action`.

This combined let to a `ssh` to `localhost` that failed.

Further considerations:

- `delegate_to`, `local_action` set `ansible_host` and `ansible_connection`, but any setting in the host_vars, playbook or task override that.
- `connection: local` only sets `ansible_connection` (`ansible_host` is unmodified), but any setting of `ansible_connection` in the host_vars, playbook or task overrides it.

So my solution was to either remove the `ansible_connection` in the host_vars, or setting the var `ansible_connection` in a task.

Answer (score -1):

That looks wrong for me.

```
- name: import profiles of VMs   
  connection: local   
  hosts: localhost   
  gather_facts: false   
  tasks:
    - name: list files
      find:
        paths: .
        recurse: no
      delegate_to: localhost
```

He is still asking me for ssh password:

```
❯ ansible-playbook playbooks/import_vm_profiles.yml  -i localhost, -k [WARNING]: Unable to parse the plugin filter file /Users/fredericclement/devops/ansible_refactored/etc/Plugin_filters.yml as module_blacklist is not a list. Skipping. 
SSH password:
```

Comment: Your answer seems more of a question than an actual answer. I'm afraid I can't help here; My suggestion is to debug with `-v` or to add a debug task to see exactly which variables are set, including the host.  I usually use `-l localhost` to limit the playbook to the localhost; I suspect `-i localhost` should work too, but I never tried, so don't know exactly how this behaves. Good luck debugging!