# Stop ansible calling SSH

Tags: ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

This is in some ways similar to [Ansible local_action on host without local ssh daemon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61295544)
which tries to only run a localhost inventory without using SSH at all.

In my case I have an actual inventory of hosts, but only want to gather information (the groups each host belongs to) from the inventory.  Everything should only need to run locally, without involving SSH at all.

```
- name: Run Over Hosts
  hosts: 'all'
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: host groups
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} {{ group_names | to_json }}"
```

I then run it using...

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml list_host_groups
```

The output of the above is later processed to generated a host to groups list.

But it still calls SSH!

Adding `-vvv` show it is doing so before even running the first task.
Heck it does not even print the SSH command like it normally does using the -vvv flags!
But SSH is being called as SSH is asking for a password.

How can I stop it calling SSH!

Comment: Is `ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml -c local list_host_groups` any better?

Comment: FWIIW, doing this via a playbook doesn't seems like the correct way to do it. Did you  had a look at [dynamic inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html) already?

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε  Nope does the same thing.

Comment: As for a better way.  That is the rub.  This was the best way that was determined from another discussion.   I have one solution that works for 1 host only using a pip library 'yamlpath' to pull out all the paths where the hostname appears in the yaml file.   But that does not work for all hosts,    The playbook works perfectly fine if ansible can SSH.  It does not even try to SSH all 500+ hosts in the inventory.  It's just this one SSH attempt at the start which fails in situations when SSH is not available.

Comment: As for 'list_host_groups'
`ERROR! the playbook: list_host_groups could not be found`